# Bucket permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I seem to have accidentally messed up bucket ownership. Now, it says "Additional permissions required to view this bucket's metadata: Ask a bucket owner to grant you 'storage.buckets.get' and 'storage.buckets.getIamPolicy' permissions (e.g., by giving your account the IAM Storage Admin role)."

I am the project owner and Google account owner.

I have tried adding IAM permissions to the bucket service account with both "Storage Admin" and "Storage Object Admin"

Answer (score 1):

If you add the Storage Admin role to your own user account in IAM, you should be able to give the service account Storage admin again on the [bucket level](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions?hl=en_US&_ga=2.62523372.-1587613234.1552349196#bucket-add).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the correct account is logged in.

Google lets you sign-in to multiple accounts simultaneously and it is easy to get confused about which account is actively logged in.

To check, click the avatar in the top right corner.